# Automatically detect which ethernet network I am plugged in to

Tags: ethernet, lan

In my Network manager I have two different Ethernet configurations: one for home and one for work. Ubuntu automatically connects to one of them (DHCP). Is it possible to detect the other one (static) and automatically connect? At present I always have to choose the static connection manually from the menu.

Answer (score -1):

1. Run this command in the terminal:

   ```
   nm-connection-editor
   ```

   A popup will appear.
2. Click the connection which you want to remove from default. Click *Edit*.
3. Click the *Ethernet* tab.
4. Uncheck the default option and click *Save*.
5. Then edit the connection you want to connect by default. Check the default option and then and the click the *Save* option.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to change the default connection. Maybe my question wasn't clear, but I am asking if I can connect to both networks automatically, depending to which one I am plugged in.

Comment: set both the connections to default and give my answer a upvote